# How to build static library with Visual Studio Qt Add-in?

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I implemented some reusable dialogs with QT in Visual Studio and compiled them as a static library for reuse.
I works good when I use static QT.
Now I have to build application that uses WebKit, so I switched to DLL-based QT. And my static library can not link now. I receive 2 errors:

```
error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl QString::~QString(void)" (??1QString@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in Qt5Cored.lib(Qt5Cored.dll)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QArrayData const * const QArrayData::shared_null" (?shared_null@QArrayData@@2QBU1@B)
```

It looks like some functions QT generates inline, and they appear in static library. Is there any workaround? Another open source libraries (libxml, for example) use preprocessor definitions to define whether we use static or dynamic library. Is there something similar in QT?
I use QT in Visual Studio 2013 (via official add-in), so I don't have .pro file where I can edit QT settings manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of problem. It is QT Visual Studio 2013 Add-In bug. How it works:

1. When you import `pro` file from QT Creator to QT Visual Studio Add-In project, it imports absolute paths. I. e. it added absolute paths to static QT include directories.
2. Now when you change QT version in Visual Studio QT settings from static one to dynamic one, it doesn't affect the imported project at all, because it uses absolute paths.
3. When I replaced absolute paths with ones relative to `$(QTDIR)`, it started to compile well.